# query two table using one parameter pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join, pdo

I have 2 table in my project `table1` and `table2` and using a parameter `id` as a column on both tables

1. I want to **create a query to select data from both table if the id exist in both table**
2. if `id` is **only in table1** I will get the row found in `table1` .
3. if `id` is **only found in table2** then I will only get row in `table2`.

   I tried using `INNER JOIN`, if first table does not contain the `id` even if the other table has that `id` it won't select, I tried `LEFT JOIN` but again the moment that the first table does not contain the if even if the second one has it i cant select. Same with `RIGHT JOIN` if second table has no `id` I can't select.

ANY idea is appreaciated

**UPDATE**

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dLY45yAT)

Comment: use UNION if columns are same

Comment: Looks like you need a `UNION`. Do both tables have the same structure?

Comment: what do you mean by same structure?same number of columns?no they dont have same number of columns

Comment: You would need to select the same amount of columns from both tables and they would need to have the same meaning (so you can use them...). Can you post the table structures and what you want to select?

Comment: GIve sample datas and output

Comment: Is there a difference between point 1 and 4 ?

Comment: yes i need to select varchar column from both tables they are both id so i can say yes same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `UNION` statement

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = 1)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

**Edit:**

If you use `UNION` to connecting two tables, the result get the field names from the first table.

```
table1
+----+-------+
| id1| text1 |
+----+-------+
|  1 | aaa   |
+----+-------+


table2
+----+-------+
| id2| text2 |
+----+-------+
|  1 | bbb   |
+----+-------+


(SELECT 't1' AS 'table', id1, text1 FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT 't2' AS 'table', id2, text2 FROM table2)


Result:
+-------+----+-------+
| table | id1| text1 | <-- field names from the first table in the UNION query
+-------+----+-------+
|   t1  |  1 | aaa   |
+-------+----+-------+
|   t2  |  1 | bbb   |
+-------+----+-------+
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b839/5

Comment: i have two select now and i am selecting specific like table1.id for 1st select then table2.id for second but why do i get `Undefined index:` for second id even if it exist when i try to interchange the select the first one who has result on the first try will be undefined since i interchange the select any idea on this

Comment: Can you post the complete query and the table structures?

Comment: I updated my answer. You try to access a fieldname which didn't exist after the `UNION`.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong so the way i should access the second item to be selected is by using the first item's name?i think i am getting it now

Comment: i think this is not the solution for me i can distinguish if the result is from `table1` or from `table2` since i need to get a specific result if from `table1` i need it to be labeled from `table2` is from `table2` i need to labeled from `table2`

Comment: Yes the `UNION` create a new temporary table and the field names are always from the first table. 
I updated my solution and the sqlfiddle link. I add in the select statement a field with a fixed string. In the result you can see from which table the result is coming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) but you would need to select the same number of columns from both tables:

```
(SELECT col_y AS the_data FROM table_y WHERE id = :id)
UNION
(SELECT col_x AS the_data FROM table_x WHERE id = :id)
```

Note that binding only one variable can work but that depends on your PDO setup. If it does not work, you need to bind 2 separate variables:

```
(SELECT col_y AS the_data FROM table_y WHERE id = :this_is_your_id)
UNION
(SELECT col_x AS the_data FROM table_x WHERE id = :really_the_same_id)
```

Comment: i have two select now and i am selecting specific like table1.id for 1st select then table2.id for second but why do i get Undefined index: for second id even if it exist when i try to interchange the select the first one who has result on the first try will be undefined since i interchange the select any idea on this

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

```
<?php


$query  = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = 1";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
do {
    /* store first result set */
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    /* print divider */
    if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
        printf("-----------------\n");
    }
} while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

?>
```